# angular - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I created an interface httpOption qui contient httpParams, when i want to set param to httpParam, i get this error

> Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

```
export interface HttpOptions {
  headers?: HttpHeaders;
  params?: HttpParams;
  reportProgress?: boolean;
  withCredentials?: boolean;
}

createUsingPOST(args: { createConventionRequest: models.CreateConventionRequest }, requestHttpOptions?: HttpOptions): Observable<string> {
    requestHttpOptions.params.append('responseType', 'text');
}
```

Comment: You've explicitly said `requestHttpOptions` is *optional*, what *do* you want to do if it isn't passed?

Answer (score 0):

`requestHttpOptions` is optional, meaning that if it's not here, it'll be `undefined`.

When you call your method without a second parameter, you're trying to read property `params` of `undefined`, which throws the error.

You have to give `requestHttpOptions` a default value if you want it to be optional, like this:

```
createUsingPOST(args: { createConventionRequest: models.CreateConventionRequest }, requestHttpOptions: HttpOptions = {}): Observable<string> {
```

However, it won't fix the issue entirely, as you'll get `Cannot read property "append" of undefined`.

So you have to decide what's the behavior you want when the second parameter isn't given.